# React useState not updating on render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I'm trying to have getAllEvents() only run when the page is first rendered and for getFilteredEvents() to run when eventFilters is updated/changed. I still want getFilteredEvents() to run when the page loads so  that it can be passed into the Events component for rendering.

However, getFilteredEvents() only seems to run when I modify eventFilters using buttons from the FilterBar component, and not when the page first loads. I can confirm this by pressing a button after render which console.log() allEvents and filteredEvents showing that only allEvents is populated. But when I console.log() allEvents in useEffect or getFilteredEvents upon rendering, it is empty. I have also tried putting getFilteredEvents() inside of the page-render only useEffect, but that doesn't work either.

```
  const [eventFilters, setEventFilters] = useState(["OTHER", "WORKSHOP", "MEAL", "SPEAKER", "MINIEVENT"]);
  const [allEvents, setAllEvents] = useState([]);
  const [filteredEvents, setFilteredEvents] = useState([]);

  const something = () => {
    console.log(allEvents);
    console.log(filteredEvents);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getAllEvents();
    setEventFilters(eventFilters.concat("ALL"));
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    getFilteredEvents();
  }, [eventFilters]);

  const getAllEvents = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(URL);
    const data = await response.json();

    setAllEvents(data.events);
  };

  const getFilteredEvents = () => {
    console.log("getFilteredEvents has run");
    setFilteredEvents(allEvents.filter(event => {
      console.log("filteredEvents is being populated");
      if(eventFilters.includes(event.eventType)){
        return {...event}
      }
    }));
  }

 return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={something}>a</button>
      <Container>
          <div>
            <h1>2021 HackIllinois Schedule</h1>
          </div>
          <div>
            <FilterBar eventFilters={eventFilters} setEventFilters={setEventFilters}/>
          </div>
        <Row>
          <Col> <AllEvents filteredEvents={filteredEvents} selectedDay={selectedDay}/> </Col>
        </Row>
      </Container>
      
     
    </div>
  )
```

Comment: `getFilteredEvents` surely *does* run when the page first loads. The "problem" - if it really is one - is that `allEvents` will still be empty, because the async call inside `getAllEvents` won't have finished yet. This is perfectly normal and can't be avoided if you're using asynchronous code. If the component is actually behaving in a way you don't want - from the user's point of view, not just from the point of view of a `console.log` - then please explain in detail what that problem is, so we can help make suggestions.

Comment: try moving `setEventFilters(eventFilters.concat("ALL"));` in `getAllEvents` function. If that works, I will put an explanation for it.

Comment: If you are not using getAllEvents outside useEffect then define it inside the useEffect.

Comment: setEventFilters(eventFilters.concat("ALL")); inside getAllEvents then-able part. getAllEvents ().then(res =>setEventFilters(eventFilters.concat("ALL")))

Comment: you need to pass allEvents to the useEffect array

Comment: @Robin, the problem is that `filtedEvents` is not populated. I know this because nothing is rendered by the `Events` component and it's logged to console as an empty array when I press the button. Upon render, I get the message "getFilteredEvents has run" in the console, but not "filteredEvents is being populated" indicating that `allEvents` is empty and therefore not populating `filteredEvents`

Comment: @AsianTemptation that's true, but it's also inevitable because you're loading data asynchronously. Assuming the `fetch` succeeds, you should see the filtered events correctly a short period (typically less than a second) after the initial load. If the delay is a problem then consider showing a loader of some sort while `filteredEvents` is empty.

Comment: @Robin, I tried adding `setTimeout` for a few seconds but that doesn't seem to help as `filteredEvents` is still empty when I press the button to `console.log` it.

Answer (score 1):

As @Robin highlighted you have to avoid page rendering until `filteredEvents` has a value. You have two options, either return a waiting component or return null as

```
  const [eventFilters, setEventFilters] = useState(["OTHER", "WORKSHOP", "MEAL", "SPEAKER", "MINIEVENT"]);
  const [allEvents, setAllEvents] = useState([]);
  const [filteredEvents, setFilteredEvents] = useState([]);

  const something = () => {
    console.log(allEvents);
    console.log(filteredEvents);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getAllEvents();
    setEventFilters(eventFilters.concat("ALL"));
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    getFilteredEvents();
  }, [eventFilters]);

  const getAllEvents = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(URL);
    const data = await response.json();

    setAllEvents(data.events);
  };

  const getFilteredEvents = () => {
    console.log("getFilteredEvents has run");
    setFilteredEvents(allEvents.filter(event => {
      console.log("filteredEvents is being populated");
      if(eventFilters.includes(event.eventType)){
        return {...event}
      }
    }));
  }

if(!filteredEvents){
return null   // just giving this hint for testing, for practicle purpose don't use this. Instead render a component showing waiting state
}

 return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={something}>a</button>
      <Container>
          <div>
            <h1>2021 HackIllinois Schedule</h1>
          </div>
          <div>
            <FilterBar eventFilters={eventFilters} setEventFilters={setEventFilters}/>
          </div>
        <Row>
          <Col> <AllEvents filteredEvents={filteredEvents} selectedDay={selectedDay}/> </Col>
        </Row>
      </Container>
      
     
    </div>
  )
```

Comment: I think I understand what you mean by avoid page rendering, but do you think you can provide some code showing how and where to do that?

Comment: if(!filteredEvents){
return null   
}

Answer (score 0):

This probably isn't a very good solution, but it works so....

```
  useEffect(() => {
    getAllEvents();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    getFilteredEvents();
  }, [allEvents]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getFilteredEvents();
  }, [eventFilters]);
```

I don't why this works and `setTimeout` doesn't, but I don't even care at this point.